# Is there a quicker way to initialise a BigQuery client?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, vmware-fusion

Using the recommended way to initialise a BigQuery client from the google documentation at [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#bigquery_simple_app_client-java) takes 15 seconds to complete. This seems very slow - is there a quicker way?

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    long nanotime = System.nanoTime();
    BigQueryOptions x = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance();
    System.out.println("getDefaultInstance " +
                                  (System.nanoTime()-nanotime));
    nanotime = System.nanoTime();
    BigQuery bigquery = x.getService();
    System.out.println("getService " + (System.nanoTime()-nanotime));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
getDefaultInstance 15453574055
getService 34049521
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 16.021s
Finished at: Tue Mar 19 14:23:54 GMT 2019
Final Memory: 7M/178M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I use JS and the client initialized in milliseconds. Can you a complete code, timestamps logs and other information to better understand the issue

Comment: Yes, it should took milliseconds. Testing with this [Quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/bigquery/cloud-client#creating-a-new-dataset-using-the-quickstart-sample), I could create a dataset in less than 1 sec.

Comment: I have added a full working test program to the original question. @enlelin are you using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somehow related to the network configuration on the virtual machine.  Changing the network settings from "Share with my Mac" to "Bridged Networking" solved the issue (see image below). It now takes 0.6 secs to initialise.

[image: VMWare Network Adapter Settings]

Answer (score 2):

This is strange. I can run the same code on my end and it took less than `200ms` to initialize. I'm running the code in a `n1-standard-4` VM and using following versions for java:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

and `1.62` version for BigQuery client:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>1.62.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It is useful to know that it can be quick. And that test eliminates a number of possible problems.